# Python 2.7 Etree/lxml minimizing

Tags: python, xsd, formatting, lxml

Im using lxml/Etree to parse and write to XSD documents.

I have the basic structure

```
tree = ET.parse('file.xsd')
# do stuff
tree.write('output.xsd')
```

But tags get *minimized* in some instances, for example:

```
<Cars>
    <Car type="Chevy"></Car>
</Cars>
```

Get shortened to

```
<Cars>
    <Car type="Chevy"/>
</Cars>
```

Is there a way to make lxml/ETree NOT do this? I've searched around and apparently this is something good - But in my case, I want the ending tags to be left as they are.

I'm parsing the whole tree, making adjustments and saving it to another file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **method** parameter of **write** method. Value on parameter if `html` or `xml`

**E.g.**

```
tree.write("output.xsd", method="html")
```

Also have **pretty print** parameter which have value True or False

e.g.

```
tree.write("output.xsd", method="html", pretty_print=True)
```

Have may parameters:

```
write(self, file, encoding=None, method="xml",
          pretty_print=False, xml_declaration=None, with_tail=True,
          standalone=None, compression=0,
          exclusive=False, with_comments=True, inclusive_ns_prefixes=None)
```

Comment: So method='html' doesn't truncate empty tags? Regards

Comment: @enrm: Yes, Correct.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for your answer